# How to connect sql database to xcode?

Tags: cocoa

I need to know how do we connect sql developer with Xcode 4.5.
 Can anyone help me with step by step procedure?

Comment: Visit [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting question. Tutorials are not meant for SO. Google them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a database on some system.

Create an instance of server, it can be any apache, tomacat, java based server.

Connect your program to that server using web-services/ xml / json.

Get and post / receive data from server to your cocoa application.